Excitation of electron when the next higher shell is full
Take $\ce{[Ne] 1s^2 2s^2 2p^6}$. If I input the $1$st excitation energy to the $1$st shell electron where will it go? And what would happen since the $2$nd shell is already filled?
For example I give $\pu{10.2 eV}$ energy to $1$st shell electron of hydrogen to excite it to $2$nd shell because $2$nd shell is empty. Similarly, in neon, if I give the sufficient energy which is required to excite 1st shell electron to 2nd shell electron then what would happen?

"Similarly" is a confusing word; the difference between 1st and 2nd shells in Ne is far greater than that in H. Anyway, suppose you give it exactly that much energy; what will happen? Certainly not an excitation to the 2nd shell, since it is already full. Chances are an electron from the 2nd shell will get ejected away.

@IvanNeretin so does it mean that the excited electron pushes one of the electrons in the outer shell and that excites further? Seems like we need to give energy equivalent to 2 subsequent ionisations?

No, there won't be enough energy for that. The electron in the 1st shell does not get excited at all; the one in the 2nd does.

Polished a proposed edit but unsure what is meant by "Simlarly" so left it - could the OP clarify? Please do this by editing the question, not in a comment. Do you mean you input 10.2 eV, or do you mean you input sufficient energy to excite an electron in a 1s shell in neon?

Into one of the empty and higher energy levels 3s, 3p, 3d  or 4s etc. depending on the energy supplied.

@IvanNeretin Edited

@IanBush Edited

@porphyrin I have given only the energy required to jump electron from n=1 to n=2, then how can it go to n=3 ?

If this energy does not correspond to a possible transition (energy and selection rules) between a full level and any empty one then the photon will not be absorbed.

Then again, the energy required to jump from n=1 to n=2 is more than enough to jump from n=2 and out of the atom altogether.

When energy is given to an atom from a photon, it is just an amount of energy. All possible processes that can have that change in energy will happen; some will be more likely than others. So it is incorrect to say that the energy is given "to the first shell electron". If the photon energy matches $\ce{1s -> 2s}$ and the $\ce{2s}$ orbital is filled then that excitation is not possible and will not occur. But the same amount of energy will be able to ionize a $\ce{2p}$ electron from the atom and that will happen.
If there is enough energy to ionize the $\ce{1s}$ electron from the atom, then that can happen and leave a vacant "hole" in the $\ce{1s}$ level, at least temporarily. The ejected electron has a kinetic energy equal to the difference between the photon energy and the ionization energy for the $\ce{1s}$ electron. This process is the basis for X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy. (After the $\ce{1s}$ electron has left, an electron will move down from a higher level to fill the hole; sometimes a second electron might be ejected.)
